# IO Error Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, io, permissions

I am having problems opening files for writing. I think the issue is with the folder permissions, however I have checked everything I could (without knowing much about Windows) and can't see the problem... The properties of the folders show shaded blue "Read-only" in the Attributes. I can change it, but after re-opening the properties box it returns the Attributes to the shaded blue for Read only. In the Security tab, it shows that I should have all the permissions (I have the admin rights). 
I can create a file using Microsoft programs, but not when using Python:

```
g=open("C:\Users\jilska\Desktop\WORK\data\MIS_CLEAN\new.txt", 'w')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-012d0f45fe10> in <module>()
----> 1 g=open("C:\Users\jilska\Desktop\WORK\data\MIS_CLEAN\new.txt", 'w')

IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename:  
'C:\\Users\\jilska\\Desktop\\WORK\\data\\MIS_CLEAN\new.txt'
```

Any ideas how I can go about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an issue with the path. Python is interpreting \n in MIS_CLEAN\new.txt as a newline. There are various ways to fix this, for example by escaping all slashes:

```
g=open("C:\\Users\\jilska\\Desktop\\WORK\\data\\MIS_CLEAN\\new.txt", 'w')
```

Comment: Of the various ways you can also use a raw string or forward slashes.

Comment: I've tried the double slashes, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Also, when I try to open the file for reading using the usual path it works fine. Would that not apply to any path location?

Comment: Can you put the updated line you're using in a comment? I've tried exactly what I posted and it works.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried it again and it did work! As a side note, why does it have a problem with writing out only, and reads fine?

Comment: Excellent. As for 'r' working fine, that should actually fail too. If you change the path to fail again, and then change 'w' to 'r', does it not give you an error?